# need to convert field name with square brackets into a javascript object

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, forms, input

I would like to convert a field name consisting of square brackets into an object in JavaScript. I have seen that PHP does convert them into an array but haven't seen one done in JavaScript despite of searching for one for several days.

Data:

```
<input name="address[permanent][name]" type="text" value="My Address">
<input name="address[permanent][street][street_one]" type="text" value="My Street One">
<input name="address[permanent][street][street_two]" type="text" value="My Street Two">
```

Result (what i want to achieve):

```
form = { address: { permanent: { name: "My Address", street: { street_one: "My Street One", street_two: "My Street Two" } } } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Untested, but your basic algorithm could be something like this:</strike>

The following works for me:

```
var form = {};
$(':input', yourFormElement).each(function(){
  var top = form;
  var path = $(this).attr('name');
  var val = $(this).val();
  var prev = '';
  while ((path.replace(/^(\[?\w+\]?)(.*)$/, function(_m, _part, _rest) {
    prev = path;
    _part = _part.replace(/[^A-Za-z_]/g, '');
    if (!top.hasOwnProperty(_part)) {
      if (/\w+/.test(_rest)) { 
        top[_part] = {}; 
        top = top[_part];
      } else {
        top[_part] = val; 
      }
    } else if (!/\w+/.test(_rest)) {
      top[_part] = val;
    } else {
      top = top[_part];
    }
    path = _rest;
  })) && (prev !== path));
});
```

Substitute `yourFormElement` with a jQuery expression to get your desired form element.

That iterates over each `:input` element (form inputs) and then for each loop attempts to break down the "path" of the name using a regular expression, at the same time creating and/or traversing the `form` data-structure that is being built up. Finally the value of the input is assigned to the leaf node that has been traversed to.

Example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/8fpLx/10/

That series of conditions inside the while loop could be simplified **a lot**, but it works.

Comment: fixed termination & parsing bugs.

Comment: a little problem! the form object needs to be like a tree. `form->permanent->(name)/(street->(street_one/street_two))`

Comment: That doesn't even match your question and `->` isn't valid JavaScript for object dereferencing (you're probably thinking of PHP or Perl). The structure as per your question is e.g: `form.address.permanent.name`

Comment: i used -> just as a representation. so sorry. and yes, it would have to be like form.address.permanent.name and i would like street to come under permanent. as well as street one and two to come under street object. here's your code http://jsfiddle.net/musaid/Fg3mU/

Comment: Look at the jsfiddle. It works exactly as per your specification.

Comment: ah, ok. I see the problem... fixing now.

Comment: I've updated both the answer and the jsfiddle. They produce *exactly* the same output as your question.

Comment: now that would be a perfect answer. well done my friend. thanks alot :)